# Watch file and watch file change

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read log file when it's change and emit changes(this part work)
The problem is I get an error :

> (node:7088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open './temp.log'
>       at Object.openSync (fs.js:457:3)
>       at new LineByLine (C:\Users\Server\Documents\rconMinecraft\node_modules\n-readlines\readlines.js:23:26)
>       at myLineReader (C:\Users\Server\Documents\rconMinecraft\node_modules\text-file-diff\index.js:22:15)
>       at TextFileDiff.diff (C:\Users\Server\Documents\rconMinecraft\node_modules\text-file-diff\index.js:63:25)
>       at Diff (C:\Users\Server\Documents\rconMinecraft\app.js:56:7)
>       at Change (C:\Users\Server\Documents\rconMinecraft\app.js:40:3)
>       at FSWatcher. (C:\Users\Server\Documents\rconMinecraft\app.js:32:7)
>       at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:321:20)
>       at FSWatcher.emitWithAll (C:\Users\Server\Documents\rconMinecraft\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:521:8)
>       at FSWatcher._emit (C:\Users\Server\Documents\rconMinecraft\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:613:10)
>   (node:7088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was 
>   not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:7088) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I now this error is because the file './temp.log' is already open. I looked for an alternative of my code but I did not find.

My code :

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});
var watcher = null;
var _Socket = null;
var path = 'C:/Users/Server/Downloads/Serv/logs/latest.log';
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    _Socket = socket;
});

WatchFile();
http.listen(80, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:80');
});

function WatchFile() {
    watcher = chokidar.watch(path, {
        persistent: false
    });
    watcher
        .on('change', path => {
            Change();
        })
}

function Change() {
    fs.copyFile(path, './temp.log', (err) => {
        console.log('this is a test');
    });
    Diff();
}

function Diff() {
    var TextFileDiff = require('text-file-diff');
    var d = new TextFileDiff();
    d.on('compared', (line1, line2, compareResult, lineReader1, lineReader2) => { /*console.log(line1 + " ////// " + line2);*/ });

    d.on('-', line => {
        console.log('File 1 : ' + line);
    });

    d.on('+', line => {
        console.log('File 2 : ' + line);
        _Socket.emit('message', line);
    });
    d.diff(path, './temp.log');

}
```

Comment: Just an idea: how about, instead of watching the specified file, watch the directory instead?